# console log value in the on ready sequelize do not change

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to **get** a **value** in **sequelize** that I **increment** by **1** in a `setInterval` but when I try to do that on the `ready` event it returns the same value every time.

I **tried** doing it in a counter ( `setInterval` ) **outside** the **listener** (**ready event**) and **it works** fine.

```
client.once("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
  Tags.sync();

  client.channels.map((x) => {
    if (x.type === "voice") {
      x.members.map(async (y) => {

        const user = await Tags.findOne({
          where: { id: ID },
        });

        user.increment("rank");

        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("start");
         setInterval(async () => {

           //Here the value is always the same
              console.log("Test", user.get("level"));
      
              user.increment("rank");
          }, millisPerHour);
        }, millisToTheHour);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can I fix it? which could be a workaround for this "behaviour"?

Comment: Try awaiting async operations like .increment

Comment: I will try but in general the "level" is being updated even if the value consolloged is not

Comment: as @Mansur mentioned, the logs are displayed before the actions, actions are still happening though

Comment: Actually i tried ti "await" them but I think I can't Just put an await in front of the .increment

Comment: await user.increment("rank"); Should work. Because your functions are already async functions.

Comment: I tried but nothing changed

Comment: So Am I missing something? You increment "rank" but you get "level". Also could you please provide the generated SQL?

Comment: No Sorry by level i mean rank

Comment: I increment rank and i want to get rank

Comment: what do you mean by "generated sql"

Answer (score 0):

As per [sequelize's docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#incrementing-and-decrementing-integer-values):

> In PostgreSQL, `incrementResult` will be the updated user, unless the option, `{ returning: false }` was set (and then it will be undefined).
>
> In other dialects, `incrementResult` will be undefined. If you need the updated instance, you will have to call `user.reload()`.

So, **if you're using PostgreSQL**, you can change user to a `let` instead of a `const`, and save the updated value to it whenever you increment:

```js
// At the start of the map function:
let user = await Tags.findOne({
    where: { id: ID },
});

// Inside of your setInterval
user = user.increment("rank");
```

If **you're using other dialects/databases**, you'll have to call `user.reload()` after incrementing:

```js
await user.increment("rank");
await user.reload();
```