# how to run an async func in setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, setinterval

How can I run an async func in a `setInterval` like in the example below?

```
 setInterval(async () => {  
            
  }, millisPerHour);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way you should run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184291/async-await-with-setinterval

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? Did you get any errors/Problems?

Comment: I tried and seems not working honestly

Comment: In what way was it not working? Can you describe the exact problem you had? What was your code, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? It would appear the problem was located elsewhere.

Comment: actually I had a problem, I also made another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069640/console-log-value-in-the-on-ready-sequelize-do-not-change and I tried to async a setInterval but probalby this is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try with this code**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    
    async function asyncCall() {
      console.log('calling');
      const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
      console.log(result);
      // expected output: "resolved"
    }
    
    asyncCall();`
```

Comment: SetInterval not setTimeout

Comment: just change setTimeout to setInterval